# OOzie HA jobs run on one or both

Tags: oozie, high-availability

I am completely new to oozie .

We want to schedule jobs in an HA implementation of oozie with 2 oozie servers.
My concern is that if I schedule a job it should run on only one of servers whichever is active.

How I would do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you configure Oozie to use ZooKeeper properly? See [this link](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/5.0.0/AG_Install.html#High_Availability_HA) on the how-to.
Oozie HA is active-active, every server will be active if it's set up properly.
Also [this blogpost](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/03/inside-apache-oozie-ha/) will help understand how HA works in detail if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks, but I have already gone through links provided by you, they are merely about how to setup HA in oozie

Comment: There is no reference of how to ensure cluster wide concurrency to be 1, despite failures

Comment: The jobs are not running on the Oozie server itself, they are running in the Yarn cluster. The Oozie servers are only responsible to submit, monitor and relaunch jobs in case of failures. They are using ZooKeeper and the underlying DB to coordinate. If you'd like to make sure that only one instance of a coordinator job is running at a time there is also an option for that: see the <concurrency> tag https://oozie.apache.org/docs/5.0.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a6.3._Synchronous_Coordinator_Application_Definition